# split single invoice pdf file into multiple pdf files with varying pages using nodejs pdf lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm trying to split the single invoice PDf file into multiple pdf files. an invoice can span across more than1 page and few invoice may be taking just one page. I want to split the pdf file into multiple pdf files as soon as it detects some keyword like invoice as top text on page

I'm using below code to split the file into multiple here it is splitting every page on pdf file into separate file, but i want to split based on the text at the top of the page like "invoice" because few invoices could be taking more than a page

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PDFDocument = require('pdf-lib').PDFDocument;

async function splitPdf(pathToPdf) {

    const docmentAsBytes = await fs.promises.readFile('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\ilovepdf_merged.pdf');

    // Load your PDFDocument
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(docmentAsBytes)

    const numberOfPages = pdfDoc.getPages().length;

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {

        // Create a new "sub" document
        const subDocument = await PDFDocument.create();
        // copy the page at current index
        const [copiedPage] = await subDocument.copyPages(pdfDoc, [i])
        subDocument.addPage(copiedPage);
        const pdfBytes = await subDocument.save()
        await writePdfBytesToFile(`file-${i + 1}.pdf`, pdfBytes);

    }
}

function writePdfBytesToFile(fileName, pdfBytes) {
    return fs.promises.writeFile(fileName, pdfBytes);
}

(async () => {
    await splitPdf("./path-to-your-file.pdf");
})();
```